# R c.Date() raises warning Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated

Tags: r, warnings

I noticed that calling c.Date() to initialize an empty date vector raises a Warning. I am on R version 3.4.0.

The warning message is :

> Warning message: In structure(c(unlist(lapply(list(...), unclass))),
>   class = "Date") :   Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as
>   NULL cannot have attributes.   Consider 'structure(list(), *)'
>   instead.

Do anyone has an explantion? How to initialize an empty DATE vector without having this warning?

A reproducible code :

```
vect = c.Date()
d = as.Date("31/12/2018", format = "%d/%m/%Y")
for(i in 1:10){
    vect = c(vect, d)
    d = d+1
}
print(vect)
```

Result is

> [1] "2016-03-31" "2016-04-01" "2016-04-02" "2016-04-03"  [5]
>   "2016-04-04" "2016-04-05" "2016-04-06" "2016-04-07"  [9] "2016-04-08"
>   "2016-04-09"

If I don't use c.Date() but c() instead.

```
vect = c()

d = as.Date("31/12/2018", format = "%d/%m/%Y")
for(i in 1:10){
  vect = c(vect, d)
  d = d+1
}

print(vect)
```

> [1] 17896 17897 17898 17899 17900 17901 17902 17903 17904 17905

which is undesirable.

Comment: *"How to initialize an empty DATE vector without having this warning?"*: `Sys.Date()[0]`

Comment: Works very well thanks.
Would have prefered a more elegant way to define it but I am very satisfied with your answer.

Comment: You can also use `suppressWarnings(c.Date())`. Perhaps best of all, though, is `vect <- as.Date("31/12/2018", format="%d/%m/%Y") + 1:10`, no loop or empty-vector required.

Comment: Thanks again r2evans,  suppressWarnings() works too.
I am using it in a loop, and trying to keep it clean and readable, avoiding initializing first iteration of the loop. 
What is surprising me is that, R deprecated somehow c.Date() and does not propose any direct way to initialize an empty date vector.

Comment: I understand your complaint, and the only thing I can offer is this: rarely do I initialize an empty vector or list of anything, instead opting to create it as a return value from one of the `*apply` functions. They used to be considerably faster than `for` loops (can still be, depending on your use). Iteratively appending to a vector or list, on the other hand, can have horrible performance; it might be fine for a few dozen, but with large objects or a lot of them, each pass through the loop will get slower in the long run. Unavoidable, it's how memory management works (in R).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

r2evans answerd my question. 
`Sys.Date()[0]`
does the trick.

I post here to mark it as resolved for future readers.