# 'structure(NULL, *)' deprecated in R 3.5.* when using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, structure, version, scale

I'm writing a program which has a step involving **ggplot2** in R. The plot's relevant steps are:

```
ggplot() +
geom_violin(data=x, mapping=aes(x=1, y=Mean_cov)) + 
geom_jitter(data=x, mapping=aes(x=3, y=Mean_cov, col=Frac_pos)) + 
scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1,3), labels=c("","")) +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 50)) + 
scale_color_gradient2(  breaks=seq(0,100,20), 
                        limits=c(0,100), 
                        low="green3", high="darkorchid4", 
                        midpoint=50, name="% covered") +
coord_flip()
```

`Mean_cov` and `Frac_pos` are `colnames()` of my `data.frame()`. **1** and **3** are unelegant solutions I found to obtain a plot that separates the `geom_jitter()` and the `geom_violin()` by a sufficient space.

This worked in `R/3.3.3` but since our sysadmin updated the default **R** to `R/3.5.2` we are experiencing plotting issues (i.e. the plot gets generated but the axes are overlapping the panel margin, instead of being contained within it). I know I could just point it to `R/3.3.3` but I would prefer to make my program compatible with newer R versions, since I want to publish it.

The warning I'm getting is quite popular in R-related error threads:

```
3: In structure(NULL, class = "waiver") :
  Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.
```

I am aware of other stackoverflow issues similar to mine, like this one:

[R c.Date() raises warning Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51751959/4681355)

However, I couldn't solve the problem following other issues so I decided to open a new one since it seems to be a ggplot2 issue.

Perhaps the error is raised because of a way ggplot2 calls some function in the background?

Here are 10 lines from my data frame:

```
Frac_pos            Mean_cov
99.78591232934406   42.783034429509
99.98996910484291   24.89770493118806
98.9460737536315    19.48427592934241
99.80868782354266   45.07804411433716
99.48891662209545   88.17287692399121
99.89221021636827   30.86539422141599
99.56238183247297   25.512161961209184
99.00406672752926   32.80431986056934
99.22226325737003   29.72798766048967
```

This is how it should look like (as with R/3.3.3):

[image: R333]

This is how it looks like with newer R versions (see that it is broader? Since I have millions of those dots, many of them fall out of the panel):

[image: R352]

Comment: As far as I can see, you are not receiving an error, but a warning. Regarding the plotting issues, they might be related or not with the warning (which is very likely generated by some `ggplot2` function). Please, post a reproducible example and maybe also the images of the two plots you get (with the old R and the new version).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited in "warning" instead of "error", and I added the figures and the reproducible data that you asked for.

Comment: Have you tried updating `ggplot2`?

Comment: I can't reproduce on `R v3.6.1`, and `ggplot2 v3.2.1`.

Comment: This problem was [fixed for `ggplot2 v2.2.1`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/commit/bd7d9d6e478f344f4064619bb4e7a1f926f2bea9) almost 3 years ago.